# Send Email with Images in body not Attachement in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-forms

I tried to send the email with an image in the body of email, the image is not an attachment.

I read the image from the media item in sitecore and i got the url of the image like  https://domain/-/media/image.ashx next step i convert to email body using LinkedResource like below code

```
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource = new 
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(imageUrl, "image/jpg");
imageResource.ContentId = "HDIImage";
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = 
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<image src=cid:" + 
imageResource.ContentId + ">" + textbody, null, "text/html");
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
```

but I have exception like the image path is not given correctly.

Comment: did you try to get the media URL with .jpg extension?

Comment: yes i tried convert .ashx into .jpg using Media.RequestAction , but i cannot able to convert that.

Comment: Taking a guess here , You should use this :- new StreamReader(MediaManager.GetMedia(sampleMedia).GetStream().Stream) Try to to convert media item to a stram and assign to LinkedResource constructor, I am hoping the constructor allows that

Comment: Thank you Abhay Dhar, Url has been convert into Stream now i can able to send image with body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I got an answer to my question. It is helpful to other developers.

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem image = new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
string mimetype=image.MimeType;
Stream stream = MediaManager.GetMedia(image).GetStream().Stream;
```

In this stage, I got an image as a stream

Next, I created the email

```
//Create two views, one text, one HTML.
var bodyMail="Test Message";
         
//Add image to HTML version
System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(stream );
imageResource.ContentId = "HDIImage";
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<image src=cid:" + imageResource.ContentId + ">" + textbody, null, "text/html");
         
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
//Add two views to message.
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```